# authlogic not working with rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using authlogic gem. I was following the railscasts video for help
http://railscasts.com/episodes/160-authlogic?autoplay=true
I run into a problem when I do the 
sudo rake gems:install
it gives me an error :

```
at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb

rake aborted!

(eval):1:in `define_callbacks': compile error

(eval):1: syntax error, unexpected tEQ, expecting '\n' or ';'
...  def self.terminatorresult == false(*methods, &block)      ...

                          ^
```

I tried uninstalling the rake gem and installing it again. 
I tried going to a lower version of rake and that also did not work.

What should I do here?

Do I need to edit the rake gem 
and include this in there..

```
base.define_callbacks :persist, :terminator => "result == true"
```

I found the above on 
http://pastebin.com/Q3eL53ZJ

If yes then how? 
If there is a better solution then please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are not trying to use the master branch with Rails 2.x it is only compatible with Rails 3.x.

Use the rails2 branch if you are on Rails 2.x, I actually just used an older version since I wanted to just maintain some legacy site without too much concern about upgrading gems. I used version 2.1.5 and it worked fine.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I first removed all my authlogic gems:

```
  gem uninstall authlogic
```

I'm using rails 2.3.15 because that is what hostgator is using.  The authlogic version that matches is 2.1.3, so I added this to config/environment.rb:

```
config.gem "authlogic", :version => '2.1.3'
```

Then did rake gems:install.  Afterwards, a `script/generate controller user_sessions` command actually generated the user_session.rb in model.